# VS Code and Vim, how do i save the register content?

Tags: vim, visual-studio-code

I'm using the Vim extension for VS Code (newest version, always update ^^), and i'm using registers on a daily basis, but i can't find a way to save them for tomorrow, or even how to use them in another window.

I'f your wondering how i use it here's how:

Press q(some key) and then do what needs to be done, then i press q after i'm finished.
When i want to use it i type @(some key) and that's it.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscodevim.vim

Answer (score 1):

this is not supported yet unfortunately!  I just ran into this.  Here is the issue to follow https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues/1658

Answer (score 0):

`q` is used for macros, not registers. Press " and then a letter key to save registers.